# For TreeView, how to make a value go to the next line instead of going past column bound and become invisible?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

My TreeView has two columns, name and description. Now for the description, if it is too long, it goes out of column bound and the rest is not visible. I want to know how I can make it go to the next line instead of going out of bounds. I looked at the manual but couldn't find anything that would that. Does anyone know how I can do this?

What happens now:

```
Name       |      Description         |
TOM        |Activities= Football, Bask| <----- Gone out of bound
BILLY      |Age = 25       

       |
```

What I expect to happen:

```
Name       |      Description         |
TOM        |Activities= Football, Bask|
           |etball,Swimming.          |
BILLY      |Age = 25                  |
```

Comment: I am not familiar with tkinter but I have used [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) to good success to achieve similar output to this. In case this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As near as I can tell, Treeview rows, aside from the optional leading icon, are a single line of single-line strings.  The only exception I know of is that an embedded `\n` in the last row will display text after \n on the next line.  The following displays `too long` on the line after the row.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns='test')
tree.pack()
tree.column('#0', width=50)
tree.column('test', width=100, stretch=True)
tree.insert('', 'end', text='one', values=('this item is\ntoo long',))
#tree.insert('', 'end', text='two', values=('short item',))

root.mainloop()
```

But when the insertion of `two` is uncommented, `short item` overwrites `too long`.  One might think of trying is to insert a multiline Label widget, but the answer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755176/tkinter-insert-a-combobox-inside-a-treeview-widget) is that only strings, not widgets, are allowed.