# How to insert image into different columns in tkinter Treeview widget?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, treeview

I just want, that image was in specified (in column named 'Country') column instead of first. Thanks!

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

s = ttk.Treeview(columns=('#1', '#2'))

s.heading('#0', text='Ip')
s.heading('#1', text='Port')
s.heading('#2', text='Country')

s.pack()

v = PhotoImage(file='uk.png')

s.insert('', 2, values=('127.0.0.1', '8888'), image=v)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thats not possible, read [Tkinter insert a Widget inside a Treeview widget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16759224/7414759)

Comment: Thanks! I won't waste more time looking into this...

Answer (score 1):

I've made it simple :) just starting with country

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
s = ttk.Treeview(columns=('#1', '#2'))
s.heading('#0', text='Country')
s.heading('#1', text='Ip')
s.heading('#2', text='Port')
v = PhotoImage(file='uk.png')
s.insert('', 2, values = ('127.0.0.1', '8888'), image=v)
s.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

#### If you don't like the image in the first place, I can imagine this, without treeview, though

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

v = PhotoImage(file='uk.png')

# header
b = Label(root, text="Ip")
b.grid(row=0, column=0)
b = Label(root, text="port")
b.grid(row=0, column=1)
b = Label(root, text="Country")
b.grid(row=0, column=2)

lista = [["800","127.1.1.",v]]

height = 2
width = 3
for i in range(height-1): #Rows
    b1 = Label(root, text=lista[i][0])
    b1.grid(row=i+1, column=0)
    b2 = Label(root, text=lista[i][1])
    b2.grid(row=i+1, column=1)
    b3 = Label(root, image=lista[i][2])
    b3.grid(row=i+1, column=2)

mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but i want to find a way , how to insert that image in 2nd or 3rd columns ✋

Comment: I think the values can contain just numbers and text